# What does this setup.m file do and what is it for?

Tags: matlab

What does [this](https://github.com/benhamner/Metrics/blob/master/MATLAB/setup.m) setup.m file do?

```
    function setup
%SETUP Adds directories for Metrics to your MATLAB path
%
%   Author: Ben Hamner (ben@benhamner.com)

myDir = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
paths = genpath(myDir);
paths = strread(paths,'%s','delimiter',':');
pathsToAdd = [];

for i=1:length(paths)
    thisPath = paths{i};
    thisPathSplit = strread(thisPath,'%s','delimiter','/');
    addThisPath = 1;

    % Do not add any directories or files starting with a . or a ~
    for j=1:length(thisPathSplit)
        thisStr = thisPathSplit{j};
        if (~isempty(thisStr)) && ((thisStr(1) == '.') || (thisStr(1) == '~'))
            addThisPath = 0;
        end
    end
    if addThisPath ==1
        if ~isempty(pathsToAdd)
            thisPath = [':' thisPath];
        end
        pathsToAdd = [pathsToAdd thisPath];
    end
end

addpath(pathsToAdd);
savepath;
```

I understand from the description that it adds directories to Matlab's search path. But which one and why? My Matlab scripts are often scattered with `addpath('data')` lines. Does this mean I don't have to do that anymore? Your comments are much appreciated.

Comment: To answer you related question - whether you need to scatter calls to `addpath` throughout your scripts. You can have a separate script/function that adds all the paths you need - it is easier this way. I usually have separate "project" scripts (for example `proj_ADHD`) that are only used to set up environment for working on a specific project - they add paths and sometimes also load files. `genpath` is useful if need to add a hierarchy of subfolders.

Comment: by the way: here you have a function that does (almost) the same but in a manner more simple to understand:  https://github.com/mmagnuski/eegDb/blob/master/eegDb_setup.m  The only difference is in not adding folders starting with `~` or `.` - the linked function checks and excludes paths starting with `.` only at the top level (in the folder where it is located).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that you are linking is a setup file for the Metrics package - it adds paths to various folders so that you can use Metrics package without setting up the paths manually.
More specifically the `setup.m` function adds all paths at the level and below where it is located. If you copy this file to any directory and run it - it will add this directory and all its subdirs and subdirs of subdirs etc. (excluding folders starting with `.` or `~`)

But I have a hunch that what you are looking for is this:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabrc.html

Answer (score 0):

This is adding the directory that setup.m is located in as well as every sub directory within that directory.  `fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))` gets the directory that the file exists in, and `genpath(myDir);` gets all of the subdirectories.  Note that this leaves out any directory starting with a '.' or a '~'

Comment: Small correction - it does not add the current directory (and its subdirs) but the directory (and its subdirs) where `setup.m` is located.